# Previously working date-formatting code returns nothing on Micromax A111

Tags: java, android, date

I am using the following code to format date.

```
private String getDate(String datestring) {
  Date date = null;
  DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  try {
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
        Locale.ENGLISH).parse(datestring);
    String formattedDate = "";
    if (date != null) {
      formattedDate = writeFormat.format(date);
    }
    Log.d("Complaint adapter", formattedDate);
    return formattedDate;
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return "";
}
```

This code works fine in some devices, but when run this same in Micromax A111, it returns nothing. That is not displayed in the given field. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `Date date`......`date=new SimpleDateFormat...`??? Need Serious Edit

Comment: Sorry, But I don't know about stderr. I am using android SDK to develop this application.

Comment: @suresh Check LogCat for errors.

Comment: Its not returning any error @Duncan

Comment: @suresh are you sure? Maybe post your logcat here for us to look at?

Comment: Yes, I copied it from internet. But it works fine on Motorola tablet, Samsung tab 2 and Sony Xperia.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the following code worked for me.

```
private String getDate(String datestring) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SimpleDateFormat currentformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat requiredformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        Date date = null;
        date = currentformat.parse(datestring);
        datestring = requiredformat.format(date);
        return datestring;
    } catch (ParseException e) { 
        Log.e("Formating date", e.getMessage());
    }
    return datestring;
}
```